# How can I redesign Magento toplinks?

Tags: html, magento

I have browsed through many articles, but none of them mention how I can go about redesigning the toplinks at the top of any Magento store.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can modify the default links which are found in the top right of my Magento store and assign an icon to each link and also spread the links across the full width of the top area.

It may include something like the below (example only).

[image]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.
My website is: www.efficienttrade.co.nz  if that helps.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `top.links` in layout xml files and add a class. Then, you can customize this class via css.

For instance,

```
    <!-- this piece of code available in rss.xml, look at the class define -->
    <reference name="footer_links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="rss" ifconfig="rss/config/active"><label>RSS</label><url>rss</url><title>RSS</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position/><li/><a>class="link-rss"</a></action>
    </reference>
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as Ogüz answer + more information:

You have to be a little bit like Sherlock Holmes.
The top links are generated thanks to a block that you can find in the layout file page.xml of your theme. Then search the block name "topLinks" in the header block (in the default theme, it's the name) and you will find `<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>`. This block topLinks is generated thanks to the block class Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links. The important method in this block is `public function addLink(...)`, it means that you will have to search into the xml layout the following element/tag `<action method='addLink'>...</action>`.

An example for the customer module, in the file customer.xml of the layout folder:

```
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
```

You should find more than one xml element which uses this kind of method. 
Pay attention, the addLink method can also be called programmatically (into PHP code), not only in layout file.

Hope it helps